# Outdated opencv script doesn't work, didn't find equivalents

Tags: python, opencv, webcam-capture

After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23593/use-webcam-to-sense-lighting-condition-and-adjust-screen-brightness), I tried the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23623/280801), that gives a python script using cv to get an image from the webcam and calculate the brightness that will be applied to the screen.

When I tried it, though, the libraries just seemed to not work. Apparently, since the time that answer was posted (in 2011), changes were made to cv and highgui, for example, is not referenced anymore. I tried to get equivalences and somehow make an workaround, but it seems to be poorly documented or my problem is just too specific. Already searched here about it with no luck. 
Here is my slightly modified version of the script:

```
import opencv
import opencv.highgui
import time
import commands


def get_image():
    image = opencv.highgui.cvQueryFrame(camera)
    return opencv.adaptors.Ipl2PIL(image)

camera = opencv.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)

while 1:
    image = get_image()
    image.thumbnail((32, 24, ))
    image = tuple(ord(i) for i in image.tostring())
    x = int((int((max(image) / 256.0) * 10) + 1) ** 0.5 / 3 * 10)
    cmd = ("sudo su -c 'echo " + str(x) +
        " > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'")
    status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    assert status is 0
```

(had to change opencv to cv because even with `python-opencv` installed opencv couldn't be found).
Any light?

Comment: capture video : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video

Comment: once you capture a frame, find its mean value by `np.mean(frame)` (you may have to convert the color frame to grayscale)

Comment: Will try that, I didn't really thought capturing video would be an appropriate approach, but now I see it's just a matter of capturing a frame very often.

Comment: Now I get this:  `gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor`

Comment: Most probably your frame is not loaded correctly. `print frame`. If it is `None`, frame is not captured.

Comment: `frame` is printing 3x3 matrices (which sounds OK). What should I return?

Comment: I've figured it out. [Here](http://pastebin.com/rSL7W88X) is the new version. Now gotta work on the algorithm, the oscilation between 4 and 5 is annoying.